# Rewrite *all* non-file requests to index.php with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm basically trying to have everything that's not a file (.css, .js, .jpg, etc...) rewrite to index.php to create sym-links. The code I have in my .htaccess file works for my root directory and for a single subdirectory So. "localhost/" and "localhost/help" both work, but "localhost/help/article-27" does not work. The .htaccess seems to rewrite *everything* when I try to use that second sub-directory, including JS and CSS files. Does anyone know why that is? Here's my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any need for the `RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]` line in there.

Comment: Does `help/` also have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

As darren mentioned as per the comments it's not required to have $1 !!.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

This will work for all the levels and CSS files whether symlink / direct links.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```